# Automatic slide numbering in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have added a label in PowerPoint 2013 with the following code to show "x of y" at the bottom of all slides, where x is current slide number and y is total number of slides:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
Dim p1 As String
p1 = " of "
Dim p2 As Integer
Dim slideNumber As String
slideNumber = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.slideNumber
p2 = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
Label1.Caption = slideNumber & p1 & p2

End Sub
```

The code works perfectly for the slide on which I have added the label e.g. it shows "9 of 29" for slide 9 of my total 29 slides, however when I copy and paste the label on other slides, it still shows "9 of 29" which is wrong as I expect it to automatically reflect the current slide number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to work across all slides, wouldn't it be simpler to have a single button whose click updates all of the slide numbers at one time?

Assuming you have a shape named "SlideNumber" on every slide:

```
Sub ForExample()
    Dim oSl As Slide

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With oSl.Shapes("SlideNumber").TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "Slide " & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & " of " _
                & CStr(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I don't know how to set a name for a shape e.g. set a shape as "SlideNumber" as it has no active properties section under Developer tab in PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: You can rename the shape in the Selection pane in all recent PPT versions or select it then do this:  ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "WhateverYouLike"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Add a new textbox if it does not exist; otherwise use the existing one. That way, you can rerun the macro after making changes to slides.

```
Sub SlideNum()
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    exist = False
    For Each oS in Osl.Shapes
        If oS.name = "SlideNum" Then
            exist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If exist = False Then
        ' convert from inch *72
        Set oshp = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 25.55*72, 14.21*72, 1.12*72, 20)
        oshp.name = "SlideNum"
    Else
        Set oshp = oS
    End If
    
    With oshp.TextFrame.TextRange
        ' .Text = CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & "/" & CStr(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        .Text = CStr(oSl.SlideIndex)
        .Font.Size = 40
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: This code is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this question after doing a Google search for "how do you add page numbers on a powerpoint with vba". I didn't realize the question being asked on this page is actually slightly different.

In case anyone else lands on this question looking for what I was looking for, here's a simpler solution for you.

```
numSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
For i = 1 to numSlides
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = msoTrue
next i
```

Comment: That may work well for you, but it doesn't answer the OPs question. Your way gives you a slide number. OP wants e.g. 14 of 42.

Comment: Sorry @SteveRindsberg I didn't read the question correctly. I'll edit my response to reflect that.

Comment: Just to circle back, @Dr Phil ... your suggestion should work nicely if OP doesn't mind going into the slide master and any needed layouts and editing the slide number placeholder that PPT inserts to add "of 42" (or whatever the current slide count is). This would need to be updated whenever slides are added/removed, but it's a very simple solution.